# how to set footer below content in react

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I have a footer which is sticky at the bottom when the content is within one line, like this:
[image]

When I have content more than one line, the footer is also at the bottom but it will cover some part of the last line content, like this: 
[image]

I am using Card.Group from semantic ui react for the content and my footer CSS is:

```
position:'absolute',
left:0,
bottom:0,
right:0
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set min-height of the container with the listing as

```
min-height: calc(100vh-(footerheight+headerheight))
```

Edit:

As the footer is position absolute the container is taking the height of the cards and flowing below the footer